# Windows Server 2003 -- Firefox 3.6 deleting all downloads after they're done

Tags: windows-server-2003

No idea what's going on. New to Windows Server 2003.
I can see the file in progress in Windows Explorer but then it disappears as soon as the file is finished downloading.

What is going on? 0.o

Comment: Have you tried to search for the file after it has downloaded to see if it somehow ended up in a different location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got an overly-protective anti-virus quarantining your files?

Other than that I have no idea!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Firefox worked for me.  It was trying to update itself.